# Union of functions with typed `this`, fails with no parameters

Tags: typescript

Below I have an example of a callback that can take an optional argument.

```
interface Context {
  hello: boolean
}

type OptionsTest =
      | ((this: Context) => void)
      | ((this: Context) => PromiseLike<any>)
      | ((this: Context, done: boolean) => void)

function container (test: OptionsTest) {

}

// This does not work!

container(function () {
  console.log(this.hello);
})

// This works!

container(function (done) {
  console.log(this.hello);
})

// This works!

type Single = (this: Context) => void;
function SingleContainer (test: Single) {}
SingleContainer(function () {
  console.log(this.hello)
})
```

Is this a typescript bug?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=8&ssc=49&pln=7&pc=7#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHtwQB5mQbwChlkALCAGwvQC5kAjddCiOEQgX0MLAE8AHFAHl+YYJgDOAFQgS8AXmIllAH2QAKdWFLAJdDFlwBKZPIB8yAG7pgAEyNLlyNZu279mSMdMWAClHQAW10IABlgAGsIAB42XjMHJxIXLR09NE8cMAAaZFtMCDpGZlYQE3MrG3tuGABXEAQxTGQETzhQaA1IOToRJpBpWTATIk5uVvB2kGh1Oob+jRGlCYkSgDpqAHNU3TXyKnQjAG5OB0IJsCmZucbxEA186aWSFfWtnYk9ympj0+4Aen+yCkaWQAHV0FAIhIAITcPiCZAAZVAmxYpi6aQ8hmGPkqdhONwWKJAaIgBkuHSgXSGdBJZJGXHpLApVygs3qt2a6meLUkb3Q2zcn32P1OQA)

Comment: Seems like a bug in TS to me; couldn't find any previous report of it in my research.  I found a bunch of near misses, but nothing specifically relevant here.  If you open a bug report I'd suggest including terms like "contextually typed" and "this parameter" along with "union of functions".

Comment: @jcalz thanks! I created a ticket here: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41213